# Notepad-like GUI text editor for Linux/Ubuntu (SSH into an Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS AWS instance)

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, vim

I am not so familiar with Linux/Ubuntu bash command line. I am currently ssh'ing (using ConEmu) into an AWS instance (Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS) in order to setup a Jupyter notebook server. However, in a part of the documentation in requires editing a file using the vim editor. Vim seems a but confusing right now to learn and I just need to edit a couple lines.

Is there something similar in linux to the windows command line:

```
notepad file_name.txt
```

that opens a text file in a GUI for editing/saving. Is there a similar command line argument in Linux? Or something I can install which will give me this ability?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot use a graphical editor when you only have a ssh session... Have a try with one of these: `vi`, `vim`, `joe`, `emacs`, ...

Comment: If you are ssh'ing into the linux box, how can you open a text file in a GUI editor? VIM seems confusing but if you just have to edit a text file, press `i` immeditaly after entering into vi to place you in **edit mode**. Then move around with h,j,l,m or with arrows if you are lucky. When you're done, press `ESC` and `:write` then `ENTER`! You're done.

Comment: I don't see how this is an off topic question. This is a common question new users have regarding linux remote access. I remember having this question, and being fortunate enough to have people nearby that helped me learn about it. I also know you can connect to the x-server on the remote box and run gedit, or other GUI editors over the wire. Perhaps this is better served in the "Super User" site, but it's kind of pedantic to say if he's editing a script or code it belongs here but if he's editing a config file it doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 5):

As it a ubuntu server, it is a CLI based server which AWS provides. You cant launch GUI tools on the AWS server

I would suggest you to learn `vim` and use it as it will be helpful in future when you are working with CLI

As you are not familiar with vim you can use

`nano <path to file>` to edit

Comment: That's a good answer, nano is simple and probably already installed. It works like your basic GUI editor. **Tip**: in the shortcuts you see at the bottom of the screen, `^X` means **Ctrl+X** `^G` means **Ctrl+G** and so on